What is the function of diode D1 in this circuit?
https://github.com/cubic-print/timeframe/blob/master/electronics/PCB_schematic_V3.JPG

This circuit is to strobe some LED's and a magnetic coil.
D2 is to provide a path for flyback voltage from the inductive coil. What is the function for D1? As far as i can tell there won't be reverse polarity on those LEDs.

people plug into wrong connectors

It's a good practice to make things symmetrical. So they could have two coils for example or whatever. Easier to not mount the diode than to patch it later, if needed.

Besides, if they drivd pwm to led, inductor might make some sense.

Both diodes serve to protect the output transistors from voltage spikes.
They basically short or shunt any voltage above 12V plus the diode forward voltage drop, as you likely already know.
D1 probably makes sure that any voltages above 12V, being induced in that line from the neighboring wires through which large currents are switched and large voltage spikes may appear, are shunted to +12V.
So I would call it an additional or cautionary protection measure, but without seeing the whole circuit I can't tell you for sure.
